# How does the 'Coat of Harms' gear work?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I recently got the 'Coat of Harms' shirt, which makes "enemies easier to melee execute":

[image: Coat of Harms - Enemies easier to melee execute.]

How does it make enemies "easier to melee execute"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you have to get an enemy down to almost the last bit of his life before you can do an execution.  With Coat of Harms, the amount of damage that is required is significantly less.  It's hard to quantify, but I'd say it's less than 20% health for an execution without, and more like less than 40% with.

This means that you can save some ammo or time if you like to play a melee character.  Also, there are certain other bits of gear that only activate when you do a finishing move, (the "Kill to Live" boot item comes to mind) so these are easier to trigger.